# Datadog showing conda debug metrics on activating conda environment?

Tags: conda, datadog

I am seeing some logs from datadog agent when I ssh into the server in which this agent is installed and running. These seem to be related to miniconda. Please let me know how to get rid of this:

```
2024-02-20 02:25:17,547 DEBUG [ddtrace.internal.remoteconfig.worker] [worker.py:111] [dd.service=conda dd.env= dd.version= dd.trace_id=0 dd.span_id=0] - [93943][P: 93943] Remote Config Poller fork. Stopping  Pubsub services
2024-02-20 02:25:17,547 DEBUG [ddtrace.internal.runtime.runtime_metrics] [runtime_metrics.py:162] [dd.service=conda dd.env= dd.version= dd.trace_id=0 dd.span_id=0] - Updating constant tags ['lang:python', 'lang_interpreter:CPython', 'lang_version:3.11.5', 'tracer_version:2.6.3', 'service:conda', '_dd.injection.mode:host']
2024-02-20 02:25:17,547 DEBUG [ddtrace.internal.runtime.runtime_metrics] [runtime_metrics.py:150] [dd.service=conda dd.env= dd.version= dd.trace_id=0 dd.span_id=0] - Writing metric runtime.python.gc.count.gen0:341
2024-02-20 02:25:17,548 DEBUG [ddtrace.vendor.dogstatsd] [base.py:629] [dd.service=conda dd.env= dd.version= dd.trace_id=0 dd.span_id=0] - Connecting to localhost:8125
2024-02-20 02:25:17,549 DEBUG [ddtrace.vendor.dogstatsd] [base.py:643] [dd.service=conda dd.env= dd.version= dd.trace_id=0 dd.span_id=0] - Connected to: ('127.0.0.1', 8125)
2024-02-20 02:25:17,549 DEBUG [ddtrace.tracer] [tracer.py:292] [dd.service=conda dd.env= dd.version= dd.trace_id=0 dd.span_id=0] - Waiting 5 seconds for tracer to finish. Hit ctrl-c to quit.
```

**EDIT**

When I comment the code which initializes the conda, the logs go away. It is the following piece of code in my `.zshrc` file which is causing the logs to show up. This line initializes conda on shell start.

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/psr/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/psr/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/psr/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/psr/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: Please add more context around your question. What does "get rid of this" mean? Are you trying to remove the agent, prevent the logs from being sent to STDOUT, disable logs from conda?

Comment: Prevent the logs from being sent to STDOUT

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your conda config is set to high verbosity somewhere. Check where your config locations are pulling from using `conda config --show-sources`. You can also use `conda config --describe verbosity` to see the current configuration. Then update your config file or use `conda config --set verbosity 1 --env` to change the config for the currently active environment. If you prefer ENV vars you can set `CONDA_VERBOSITY`.

If that doesn't work, it could be that the default log level for `ddtrace` has been changed and the ENV var `DD_TRACE_DEBUG=true` has been set. Check this by running `printenv DD_TRACE_DEBUG` in your terminal.

Finally, if the environment does not contain the configuration, it is likely in the code. Search your codebase for where the logger is being defined (likely where you will see `import logging` or `from ddtrace import tracer`) or find the string `setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`.

If you cannot alter the code or find where the logger is being configured, the other option is to change how the code is being invoked so you can redirect output, e.g. `python script.py > /dev/null`

Comment: By default the verbosity was commented out. I tried changing to 1 using the command above and also setting the env variable but still no effect. `conda config --show-sources` gives a blank output.

Comment: Updated answer to include checking for `DD_TRACE_DEBUG` ENV var

Comment: Nothing in OP indicates Conda configuration is the issue - those are not Conda debug messages. There is nothing in Conda (or common extensions) that use `datadog`.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Both the title of the question and the line "These seem to be related to miniconda" did in fact suggest that conda was the issue. I'm not deeply familiar with conda, and I understand it can run scripts on activation, so I was trying to gather context and help the asker based on what I did know.

Comment: @bwest - `DD_TRACE_DEBUG` hasn't been set. Still not sure why this is happening. I tried to revert back the default configuration of logs enabled to be false (`logs_enabled: false`) which was required for my services on this server. Still getting the above mentioned logs in the console.

Comment: The log level config must be in the code itself then. I posted info on how you might find that, or how to redirect output if you can't edit the code.

Comment: @bwest I am not sourcing my code anywhere so the logs shouldn't be related to my code on the initial setup. I updated the question with more details after debugging.

Comment: @merv I doubt that `conda` and `datadog` being unrelated. Are there any global variables that could have been shared by other services? I am using default configuration for `conda` throughout (tried it on clean ubuntu server as well).

Comment: Okay then what are the contents of the scripts being run? What is in conda.sh and shell.bash? Or edit your init script to route output to /dev/null, e.g.  appending  '> /dev/null' to end of lines 5 and 8.

Comment: conda.sh: https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/main/conda/shell/etc/profile.d/conda.sh. Sorry not sure how to find `shell.bash`.

Comment: Edit your .zshrc to pipe stdout from the scripts to /dev/null as I suggested and the problem should stop.

Comment: It's this command `eval "$__conda_setup"` that causes the logs to show up. It's already outputing the command to `/dev/null`, what should be changed?

Comment: Change line 5 to `eval "$__conda_setup" > /dev/null` and line 8 to `. "/home/psr/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" > /dev/null` as I mentioned before.

Comment: I changed the line but that deactivates conda loading environment by default and when I activate a virtual environment using conda activate, the logs come back.